# Excel Combine Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got part of a matrix in `A1:J5` and another part a matrix in `A21:J25`. How do I combine these ranges to get the 10x10 matrix?

I'm imagining a function `APPEND` like:

```
=MINVERSE(APPEND(A1:J5, A21:J25))
```

I would copy both ranges somewhere next to one another, but I'm doing this too many times to be practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following **array formula**:

```
=MINVERSE(IF(ROW($1:$10)<6,A1:J10,A16:J25))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

When inside an array formula, the inner `IF(...)` expression generates the desired 2D array so that you can apply on it any function, such as `MINVERSE` or any other function working on arrays.

---

[image]

Comment: How would I do this dynamically? Suppose I were unsure about the size of the matrix.

Comment: @Will I can't answer without more specific details. Please feel free to write another question with as much details as possible.